# How to install packages on portable python

Tags: python, pip, failed-installation

Good morning,

i'm trying to install a package on portable python. I found that i do not have the easy_install.exe file, I just have the easy_install.py file.

I tried the following from prompt_CDOS:

```
    1)
C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.1>app\py
    thon.exe textract-1.6.1.tar\textract-1.6.1\setup.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "textract-1.6.1.tar\textract-1.6.1\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup
      File "C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.
    1\app\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.
    1\app\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.
    1\app\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 103
        except ValueError, e:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax


2)
C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.1>App\py
thon.exe App\easy_install.py textract-1.6.1.tar\textract-1.6.1\setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App\easy_install.py", line 4, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.easy_install import main
  File "C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.
1\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
  File "C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.
1\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.
1\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 103
    except ValueError, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

any suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax

```
except ValueError, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

is for Python 2. The error is from the file `C:\Software\Portable Python 3.2.5.
1\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py`. It seems you have a wrong version of `setuptools` installed. You have `setuptools` for Py2 but you need `setuptools` for Py3.

Comment: [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), [pip](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: the problem is that i need to instal setuptools on portable python... I tried to follow the instructuon on the link that you suggested, but i get some errors... could you please be more explicit on how I can install pip (or just tesseract) on portable python (i downloaded it from here: http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython3.2.5.1/)

Comment: Python 3.2 is too old to work. From http://portablepython.com/: *Portable Python is not being developed anymore. At the moment there are several better and more up-to-date alternatives*.